Is it ok to cast a void* pointer, pointing to a buffer, multiple times to pointers of different structs?
I have been trying to implement a TCP/IP stack in C++ for learning.
The issue is when I try to interpret the Ethernet frame and extract information from the header. I use memcpy(),
  std::memcpy(&Des,
           static_cast<uint8_t*>(Rx_Frame.payload)+ETH::preample_SFD_Size,
           ETH::Phy_Addr_Size);

but when I looked at lwip, it just casts the Ethernet frame pointer into a pointer to another struct (smaller than the data in the buffer) and dereferences the struct.
/* points to packet payload, which starts with an Ethernet header */
  ethhdr = (struct eth_hdr *)p->payload;

I read before that it's undefined behavior. Is it okay in this case, as the Ethernet frame is pointed to by a void* which cannot be dereferenced? Is it not considered type-punning in this case? If it's not, am I not allowed to cast it to another struct because this will be considered type-punning?

You need to add more details, such as the specific line(s) of code you're referring to.

First, if you are asking about C++, do not tag C. The rules are different in the different languages. Second, you have probably asked the wrong question. There are different rules for converting a pointer (using a cast) than for actually using the pointer to access data. The former are more liberal, but you need to do the latter. Third, those rules depend on what declarations are visible, details of those declarations, where the pointer came from, and more. Fourth, a C++ implementation may support aliasing even if the C++ standard does not define it.

Depending on the compiler, it MAY work as expected. Especially in C.  But technically, it IS type-punning, and in C++ it IS undefined behavior and DOES violate Strict Aliasing rules, so don't do it if you can avoid it.  memcpy() is the safe and correct approach.

@RemyLebeau I think the strict aliasing rules are relaxed somewhat for allocated objects having no declared type, which seems to be the case if lwIP is using malloc or it's own malloc-like memory allocator, depending on how the underlying memory region is defined.

These are presumably POD structures, since I expect it's reusing the C struct definitions. Does that make any difference? @RemyLebeau

@Barmar Doesn't matter. It is still technically illegal/UB in C++. Don't use unions or pointer casts for type punning

@IanAbbott No, the strict aliasing rules are not relaxed just because you use malloc. If in the case of LWIP something were to write to memory backing p->payload by any type other than struct eth_hdr with the exact same pointer, you are far off into in UB land. You are not even guaranteed to see the changes. That's also the constraints under which type punning works together with malloc etc. - no other type can possibly alias once you have used the allocated memory with a specific type.

@Ext3h I meant that since an allocated object has no declared type, any access that modifies the allocated object also changes its effective type to that of the lvalue used to access it (C17 6.5 paragraph 6). So when checking whether the strict aliasing rule has been broken or not, there are fewer cases to consider for an allocated object than there are for objects with a declared type.

This is technically UB but in practice every major compiler handles this correctly. And in fact lots of existing code depends on that behavior. Changing it would be catastrophical.
